# Cannot choose method from method group for File.Exists()

Tags: c#

I am getting the error "Cannot choose method from method group. Did you intend to invoke the method".

```
if ((!File.Exists(pathString + "\\" + fileName + ".cs")) &&
                (!File.Exists(pathString + "\\" + fileName + ".vb")) &&
                (!File.Exists(pathString + "\\" + fileName + ".c")) &&
                (!File.Exists(pathString + "\\" + fileName + ".cpp")))
```

Comment: I copied this into linqpad and it works

Comment: You need to post more code, the declarations for pathString and/or fileName are probably at fault

Comment: Try using "System.IO.File.Exists" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably pathString or fileName being a method rather than a string

Answer (score 6):

Just use `using SO=System.IO.File.Exists` in top of the program and use `SO.File.Exists`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `pathString` or `fileName` are actually a method name and not a local or accessible field.  Since it resolves to a method name the compiler is expecting a parens to follow the name in order to invoke it.  To fix this figure out which is the method name and follow it with parens

```
pathString()
```